# lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: attempt to concatenate field 'cookie_sessionid' (a nil value)

Tags: nginx, lua, cors, reverse-proxy

*/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default*:

```
location /pine {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:6285;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    access_by_lua_file /home/akuznetsov/auth.lua;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9100;
}
```

*auth.lua* (version 1, works fine):

```
ngx.req.set_header('x-user-id', ngx.var.cookie_sessionid)
```

*auth.lua* (version 2, not working):

```
ngx.req.set_header('x-user-id', 'session:' .. ngx.var.cookie_sessionid)
```

in */var/log/nginx/error.log* i get this error:

```
2016/04/06 16:13:10 [error] 14183#0: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /home/akuznetsov/auth.lua:2: attempt to concatenate field 'cookie_sessionid' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
/home/akuznetsov/auth.lua:2: in function </home/akuznetsov/auth.lua:1>, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "OPTIONS /pine HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost:6285/chart/kjckCBcG/?pine=http://localhost/pine"
```

What's wrong with concat?

Comment: this is not a debugging service... and WTF? What wrong in concat? is not an appropriate question either. Get some manners please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngx.var.cookie_sessionid` is `nil` and just as message tell you, you can't concatenate (i.e. `..`) that. Provide `if` check with logic to handle this case or use `ngx.req.set_header('x-user-id', 'session:' .. ngx.var.cookie_sessionid or "")` if you okay with using empty string as default.